# error in product widget after deployment on playstore

Tags: flutter

when I build my app in android its apk build perfectly and app run smoothly and all the fuction and widget shows fine,
but when i uploaded the app on playstore only images shows and all the textfields disappeared form the widget,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IaQV.jpg)

Comment: The grey boxes suggest there is error. Probably not able to load data and you got some error. What you can do is run app with your realDevice in debugMode through USB cable. So, you can see error in debug console.

Comment: Something is coming as null. Check that out.

Comment: It happens most commonly when you are using `Expended` widget out side the `Column` or `Row`. add some of your code to understand the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check widgets and its parent widgets but maybe its not fix your issue.

**So check this steps. Each step is different, do not use them all together.**

- **1. check widgets** *

It happens most commonly when you are using Expended widget out side the Column or Row.
To solve this error, your child widget must have the expected parent widget. Some of the widget and their parent widgets are:

[image]

Make sure to have the right parent for all the widgets using this Table, and you will be good to go!

- ***2. Use extendBody property of Scaffold widget***

> return Scaffold(
> extendBody: true,
> ...

- ***3. Size configuration***

Your widget dimensions may not have been initialized yet while your screen layout is loading. Try to print logs of size values in debugging. it may not be initialized or 0 value.

- ***4. Dependency injection***

if you are using some dependencies to get size of device or some dependency management packages (As getx) try this steps.

1. Disable packets from fetching data from classes.
2. Define the screen size and dimensions in the page or class where you get the error.
3. Temporarily comment out functions such as `size = sizepackage.getScreenwidth()`; because moving data into the class may cause errors.
4. get size dimensions from intra-class variables. like width = size.width. You can use MediaQueryData with context temporarily.

So example:

if you have Dimensions class for managing your device size.
use like this.

```
final width = Dimensions().getSize().width;
```

not like this:

```
_dimensions = Get.find... or Bloc or other Provider package
final width = _dimensions.getSize().width;
```

***5. if your issue is fixed with this way put some func. to wait provider to load size configuration***. How:

- - extend class with WidgetsBindingObserver
- - put this initState `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);`
- - watch is loaded size veriables or changed variables with `void didChangeMetrics() {`
- - Update your dimensions with their latest version. and refresh state in `didChangeMetrics()` func.

  **setState(() {
  previousSize = newSize;
  });**
- - do not forget to remove WidgetsBindingObserver in `dispose()` func.
    **WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);**